# Select files from a list of files

Tags: linux, bash

I have a list of filenames which look like this:

```
tRapTrain.Isgf3g.2853.2.v1.primary.RC.txt       tRapTrain.Yox1.txt
tRapTrain.Isgf3g.2853.2.v1.primary.txt          tRapTrain.Ypr015c.txt
tRapTrain.Isgf3g.2853.2.v1.secondary.RC.txt     tRapTrain.Yrm1.txt
tRapTrain.Isgf3g.2853.2.v1.secondary.txt        tRapTrain.Zbtb12.2932.2.v1.primary.RC.txt
```

Now i need to select the files with primary.txt and all the files where no final suffix is found. final suffix == primary.RC.txt , secondary.RC.txt, secondary.txt.

So my desired output will be:

```
tRapTrain.Isgf3g.2853.2.v1.primary.txt
tRapTrain.Yox1.txt
tRapTrain.Ypr015c.txt
tRapTrain.Yrm1.txt
```

I tried to do it with `ls tRap*primary.txt` but cant figure out how to do both selections at once. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Shopt:

```
$ shopt -s extglob
$ ls !(*primary.RC.txt|*secondary.RC.txt|*secondary.txt)
```

Meaning:

```
!(pattern-list)
Matches anything except one of the given patterns.
```

Comment: Thanks, But was does shopt exactly? Creating a list of all the dirs and files in the current directory?

Comment: shopt is a command which in this case enables extended globbing. The ! would not work as above without setting the extglob option.

Comment: "shopt -s" enables some shell feature. In this case it is "extglob" feature, which enables extended pattern matching.

Answer (score 2):

You can use *find*:

```
find * -type f -not -name "*.secondary.RC.txt" -not -name "*.primary.RC.txt" -not -name "*.secondary.txt" -print
```

Comment: Thanks it works perfectly and FAST! ( i have 10K plus files to look for)

Answer (score 1):

I would use an inverted grep match:

```
ls tRap* | grep -v "\.RC\." | grep -v "\.secondary\."
```

This should get rid of anything with ".RC." or ".secondary." in the title, which sounds like what you want.

This may not be the most elegant, but it works.

Comment: INdeed it is not the most elegant but it works smooth i will try which of the answers is most suitable for me and than accept that answer.

Comment: Parsing the output of `ls` is inappropriate, as it will fail to work as intended if any of the file names contain a newline.

Comment: @chepner - But in reality, it's not very likely.